# How to user SCNMorpher

Tags: scenekit

I'm trying to use SCNMorpher but I can't do it at all... could someone explain to me where is my mistake?

This is my code

```
 let cubeRoot = SCNScene(named: "Art.scnassets/shapekey.dae")!
    let cube = cubeRoot.rootNode
    
    let geometry = cube.childNode(withName: "Cube", recursively: true)!.geometry!

    let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
    
    let morpher = SCNMorpher()
    morpher.targets = [geometry]
    
    node.morpher = morpher
    node.morpher?.setWeight(1, forTargetNamed: "Anim1")
  
  
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

And my [file dae](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/sIBstfGp#link)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, this is the code that works:

```
let cubeRoot = SCNScene(named: "Art.scnassets/shapekey.scn")!
let cube = cubeRoot.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Cube", recursively: true)!
cube.morpher?.setWeight(1, forTargetNamed: "Anim1" )
```